# Apply a texture and a toon shader at the same time

Tags: materials, shaders

I've been using a simple toon shader to give objects basic shading in Blender, the idea being that I can then export the Freestyle lines and colour the result in a conventional art package to get the look I want.

Here's an example using a highly exaggerated shading value (the real one is less extreme, this is just for demonstration purposes)

As an aside I noticed the "white" part isn't actually white, but light grey, and I'd like to fix that if at all possible, but that's another problem.

[image]

Thanks to [Paul O'Caggegi's tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIBmH8rVoIA) I've recently discovered you can get a texture to be applied to an object with no shading at all by simply omitting any shaders.  If I apply a texture made in my art package of choice that's done that way then this is what I get.

[image]

What I want to do is combine these effects so that the texture gets applied first, and then the toon shader is applied to darken it as appropriate.

How I would do this normally in a 2D art application is create a multiply layer above the colour layer and then paint into that with a purple colour with the multiply layer at about 50% opacity.  That provides fairly pleasing shading in most circumstances.  I'd like to replicate that in Blender.

Naturally my first thought was the multiply node, but the end result is monochrome.

[image]

Then I tried the mix node, but this doesn't seem ideal either because it just overlays the toon shader on top of the texture, where I want to have the toon shader darken it (in the 2D world, "multiply" treats each colour as a value between 0 and 1, with 1 being the brightest value, therefore multiply one colour with another will darken the result).

[image]

Is there a way to mix these two shaders together in the way I'm trying to achieve?

---

EDIT: I discovered the Separate and Combine nodes and thought I'd try doing it on a per-channel basis.  The results are a bit closer to what I'm trying to do, but a) this seems needlessly overcomplicated and b) the multiply effect is too strong.  Like I said I normally only apply it at 40-50% opacity in 2D.  But for the record, here's how the result looked:

[image]

Comment: From the fourth picture above, you can replace the "mix shader" by a "mix rgb" node, set hit to 'darken', for instance. And tune the 'fac' value.

Comment: @lemon Found the node you were talking about and it works pretty well, the one big change is I decided to use multiply instead of darken as the former gives a more pleasing (to me) mix.  If you put that as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a *'mix RGB'* node in this situation and set it to either *'multiply'* or *'darken'*, then tune the mix factor.

[image]